# Different results in estimating 3PL model parameters in IRTPRO and mirt(R)

Tags: r, item-response-theory

Can someone explain why I obtain different a, b, and c parameters estimates when I use IRTPRO3 and the package mirt from R?

The method both uses are Bock and Aiken (1981) - IRTPRO calls BAEM and R calls EM.

I have estimated the parameters with default options both in IRTPRO and with mirt package, but the results are quite different.

My sample consists of 96 items with 180 respondents.

In IRTPRO the configurations (from mysets.irtpro) are

```
Estimation:
    Method = BAEM;
    E-Step = 500, 1e-005;
    SE = S-EM;
    M-Step = 50, 1e-006;
    Quadrature = 49, 6;
    SEM = 0.001;
    SS = 1e-005;
Scoring:
    Mean = 0;
    SD = 1;
Priors:
    (Q_1, Slope[0]) = Lognormal, 0, 1;
    (Q_1, Guessing[0]) = Beta, 4, 16;
    (Q_2, Slope[0]) = Lognormal, 0, 1;
    (Q_2, Guessing[0]) = Beta, 4, 16;
    (Q_3, Slope[0]) = Lognormal, 0, 1;
    (Q_3, Guessing[0]) = Beta, 4, 16;
    (Q_4, Slope[0]) = Lognormal, 0, 1;
    (Q_4, Guessing[0]) = Beta, 4, 16;
    (Q_5, Slope[0]) = Lognormal, 0, 1;
    (Q_5, Guessing[0]) = Beta, 4, 16;
.
.
.
```

And in R I ran

```
mirt(test_result, 1, itemtype='3PL')
```

The first 10 results for estimated parameter in **R** are

```
           a        b     g u
Q_1    0.413   -3.454 0.062 1
Q_2    0.807   -0.115 0.262 1
Q_3   -0.460    3.967 0.249 1
Q_4    3.827   -1.121 0.962 1
Q_5    2.896    0.090 0.636 1
Q_6    0.328   -1.556 0.030 1
Q_7    0.931    2.879 0.003 1
Q_8   -5.402   -2.415 0.058 1
Q_9    2.810   -0.406 0.810 1
Q_10   0.003  -18.079 0.161 1
```

The first 10 results in **IRTPRO** are

```
           a                       b                     g
Q_1     0.39                    -2.92                   0.2
Q_2     0.77                    -0.12                   0.19
Q_3     0.13                    -14.18                  0.2
Q_4     0.8                     -5.77                   0.2
Q_5     0.69                    -1.7                    0.2
Q_6     0.31                    -0.36                   0.19
Q_7     0.37                    109220.43               0.09
Q_8     0.37                    26016.14                0.08
Q_9     0.95                    -2.75                   0.2
Q_10    0.12                    0.43                    0.21
```

Is there some setting that is different in the two applications?

Comment: Look at your syntax. The first contains priors, and are therefore MAP estimates, while mirt has no priors, and is therefore ML.

Comment: Thanks a lot @philchalmers. Would you know how to set accordingly the IRPTRO priors `(Q_1, Slope[0]) = Lognormal, 0, 1;  (Q_1, Guessing[0]) = Beta, 4, 16;` to R - mirt?

Comment: Yes, for the most part at least (`mirt` treats the guessing parameters differently for theoretical reasons), but this is bordering on a question that should be asked on stack exchange or on the mirt-package forum; how-to and coding-based questions are generally not appropriate here.